# Check if query is empty is null before rest of query steps

Tags: powerquery

Good morning everyone,

I'm trying to edit a query that takes a worksheet from an Excel file (as a parameter), then conditions this for other query steps that include appending further down the query chain.

However, in some excel files, this worksheet is effectively blank, containing only:

**Column1**

**null**

**null**

I want to create a step in the query that checks whether the excel worksheet is like the above, and then create columns (Field_code, and Dev_status) in the same format as other queries so that it does not break the append step.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Full code from the advanced editor below:

```
let
FilePath1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="FilePath1"]}[Content]{0}[Column1], 
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(FilePath1), null, true), 
#"Technical(Oil)1" = Source{[Name="Technical(Oil)"]}[Data] 
in 
#"Technical(Oil)1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add two new steps; first declare the transformations you want to do if the table is Empty (`WhenNull`) then use if statement which test to see if your table is empty with (`Table.IsEmpty(#"Technical(Oil)1")`) if true then return your new step otherwise return the table.

```
let
    FilePath1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="FilePath1"]}[Content]{0}[Column1], 
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(FilePath1), null, true), 
    #"Technical(Oil)1" = Source{[Name="Technical(Oil)"]}[Data],
    WhenNull = Table.AddColumn(
            Table.AddColumn(#"Technical(Oil)1","Field_code", each null)
                ,"Dev_status", each null),
    Result = if Table.IsEmpty(#"Technical(Oil)1") then WhenNull else #"Technical(Oil)1"
in
    Result
```